# Can a Rogue Coup De Grace twice against a sleeping opponent in a single power?

Tags: dnd-4e

In a recent battle my rogue was in, I knocked out a wizard with one of my favorite powers.. uh.. **Knockout**.  The text says:

> **Hit**:...and the target is knocked unconscious (save ends).  If the
>   unconscious target takes any damage,
>   it is no longer unconscious.

Deciding I didn't like sleeping Wizards I then unleashed my other favorite **Circling Predator**:

> **Hit**: 1[W] + Dexterity modifier damage.
>   **Effect**: You can shift 1 square and must end adjacent to the target.  Then
>   make a secondary attack against it.
>   **Secondary Attack**:  Dexterity vs AC
>   **Hit**: 1[W] + Dexterity modifier damage, and you gain combat advantage
>   against the target until the end of
>   your next turn.

The group all agreed that I would get a Coup De Grace on the first hit, for sure.  What we weren't sure about is whether the second attack of the **Circling Predator** power allows for a second Coup De Grace.  My gut instinct is no, but I was curious what the rules say about it.

Can you perform two Coup De Grace's against an unconscious opponent who wakes after taking damage, if it's with a single power?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would think the answer is no, unless once awake the target remains in a status that's susceptible to CdG - such as tied up.

Comment: +1. Has the target taken damage? Yes? Then they are no longer unconscious :)

Answer (score -5):

I would say no because if coup de grace succeeds, the creature is dead.

Comment: Hi Baja... Could you expand on this answer a bit? Lots of legal things can leave a creature dead (like succeeding on a Coup de Grace with the first hit of Circling Predator), so that doesn't rule it out on its own.

Comment: This is incorrect per the 4e rules. You have to meet a certain damage threshold to actually kill an enemy with a coup de grace in 4e (enemy's bloodied value).